# spacing after \paragraph in a document

Tags: spacing, sections-paragraphs

I want to put a space between the paragraph header and the paragraph itself. But all I have tried so far, didn't work. Using `\paragraph` the header and the body are in the same line, whereas I want to skip at least a line between the header and the body of paragraph.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}     
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\paragraph{the header}
\vspace{1cm} % I want to skip a line or add space between header and the body of paragraph
body of the paragraph

\end{document}
```

I am using a book document, for all the answers I have seen so far are for article document or for scrbook document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, `\paragraph` style was fixed in `book.cls` as no below space with text runon with the heads, if you need below space then follow the below tag:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}     
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {-3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {10pt}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\section{section}
Test
\subsection{subsection}
Test
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
Test
\paragraph{the header}
body of the paragraph

\end{document}
```